# How to get keyof individual item in a generic array?

Tags: typescript, generics

I am scratching my head around how to implement a generic array such that each item in the array is validated against its own keys. I have few objects that implement a common type plus their own set of properties:

```js
type Table<T> = {
  id: number
  name: string
} & T

const A: tA = { // tA extends Table
  id: 1,
  name: 'table1',
  prop1: 'hello',
  prop2: 'world'
};

const B: tB = { // tB extends Table
  id: 1,
  name: 'table2',
  foo: 'baz',
  bar: 'daz'
};
```

Then I have a function that takes a list of maps from one table to another:

```
type Map<T, S> = {
  name: string,
  map: {
    from: keyof T,
    to: keyof S
  }
}

const doSomething = <T>(maps: Map<T, S>[]) => {}
                                 // ^^^ how to make this dynamic for each item?
```

Now how do I make typescript validate that each item I pass in the array only has the key of its own, not something else? Something like:

```js
doSomething<tC>([  // tC extends Table
  <tB>{
    name: 'map1',
    map: {
      from: 'cProp1'
      to: 'foo'    // pass as foo is in tB
    }
  },
  <tA>{
    name: 'map1',
    map: {
      from: 'cProp1',
      to: 'bar'    // fail as bar is not in tA
    }
  }
])
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved it. I filled in the dots regarding some of your types just so I could get things working on the TypeScript Playground.

```
type Table<T> = {
  id: number
  name: string
} & T

type eA = {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
}

type tA = Table<eA>

type eB = {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}

type tB = Table<eB>

type eC = {
  cProp1: string;
}

type tC = Table<eC>

const A: tA = { // tA extends Table
  id: 1,
  name: 'table1',
  prop1: 'hello',
  prop2: 'world'
};

const B: tB = { // tB extends Table
  id: 1,
  name: 'table2',
  foo: 'baz',
  bar: 'daz'
};

type zMap<J, K> = {
  name: string,
  map: {
    from: keyof J,
    to: keyof K
  }
}

const doSomething = <U, R>(maps: zMap<U, R>[]) => {}

doSomething<tC, Table<any>>([
  {
    name: 'map1',
    map: {
      from: 'cProp1',
      to: 'foo'
    }
  } as zMap<tC, tB>,
  {
    name: 'map1',
    map: {
      from: 'cProp1',
      to: 'prop1'
    }
  } as zMap<tC, tB>,
])
```

I renamed `Map` to `zMap` as it was getting confused with ES2015's `Map` type.

I used different names/letters for the different generic parameters. That's just something I do so I don't confuse myself while looking through code and forget which `T` I'm looking at.

[TypeScript Playground to show error on second `zMap`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgIwDYQDwwHxQLxQN4BQUUAlgCYBcUAdgK4C2CEATkTXPRFQM7DMnUA5gQC+UAGSwCBUJCgQAgjnxswzAPZgAjDz4DBAblUawAJl38hRkdNnRgS3PGRpFGW+GgQAQssLEAM3V1C30jYgQ4ZlCrUQ85YF8nRBRUH3cZT3kAYT82AGMABRMdKF5LQzjMhNzklzTsjPz1al4oBSoHPygAeh6oLogAD2AIajJuWBSINnIqLQAaNmoOLigAcmBprXWl4jVNUvWACwgkJHVd401zDYB3dWYkMnXRIwJm1uAob06k-F6-US8hGYwmUxcs0oUEWy1WVE201MV0CwQRkQAXiioJFohsyHAsW94tAMQBZOBgVAAKQWUAA0lhcP52JwYoI9lB6JSqCzAhp6FQANYQEDqAJQWlsYjAEJQEViiX0tg2GwfFptMjqADK6k4wGO+mUqAAqnSAEoYAAU3LA3Co5MppotGAA2gBdACUOCweDVWt1+sNQlQwGydOcqTg1BAGGtrrYfNZa3Wtp2nOItt50uIUACAoRRRK2NzAzl6yClxzNmIYjgk0dVLDdMSGE5SZWbI2aZLXJ5KlL-L1heKh17MvLB20r1LNagdYbFKb4YG3jbBC9QA)

Comment: Ah the `as` transformation! awesome!! thank you so much. And thanks for the ts playground example.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to manually define the overloads.

```
function doSomething<T, U>(maps: [Map<T, U>]): void;
function doSomething<T, U, V>(maps: [Map<T, U>, Map<T, V>]): void;
function doSomething<T, U, V, W>(maps: [Map<T, U>, Map<T, V>, Map<T, W>]): void;
// ...more overloads
function doSomething<T, U>(maps: Map<T, U>[]): void; // fallback
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. While overloading works, I could not keep overloading for n number of second params. I am accepting the other answer which uses the `as` keyword. This answer also has been a good learning for me. Thank you!